# Is the process in which the .net application run unmanaged or is it the normal windows process?

Tags: .net

Is the process in which the .net application run unmanaged , i mean ,is it the normal windows process ? I read some where that thats why .net provides default appdomain , which act an interface between the unmanaged process and the managed .net application running inside it .

Answer (score 1):

There is only one kind of process on Windows.  That a .NET process executes machine code that's generated on-the-fly is not relevant, the machine code is no different from the kind that's executed in an unmanaged process.  And a .NET process runs lots of unmanaged code, like Windows API functions, just like an unmanaged process.

AppDomains have nothing to do with unmanaged code.  It is merely an abstraction that's available in managed code since memory is allocated in a managed way.  Which allows it to be unallocated in a one fell swoop, much like a process.  Just a lot more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, it is just a normal process.

Maybe someone can expand on the technical details.